# Adding a new view for a particular list item: Android List View

Tags: android, android-listview

I am implementing "Swipe to Delete" functionality in a list view in android. 
So after the user swipes I want to change the view of the list item that was swiped with a different view which says: Delete - Yes/No.

I am not being able to figure out how to replace the view at a particular position in the list view.

Could someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: Make a custom xml file for it and inflate it.

Comment: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Yes i would be doing that, but the question is where to put this inflated view?

Comment: why not just have swipe/delete cause a dialog popup? Otherwise you'd have to implement that view change in your custom adapter i think